# Find the 100th digit of $( 1 + \sqrt 2 )^{3000}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

What is the 100th digit to the right of the decimal point in the decimal representation of 
 $$( 1 + \sqrt 2 )^{3000}\ ?$$

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean $(1+\sqrt{2})^{2000}$ or something like that?

Comment: I'm assuming you have already tried Wolfram-Alpha-ing it up?

Comment: sorry guys, just edited it

Comment: The way the question is asked hints that this number must be very very close to a simple rational, otherwise computing the $100^{th}$ digit would be a nightmare.

Comment: It is also useful to know that (somewhat by guessing, but I mean $\vert 1-\sqrt 2\vert$ is $<0.5$ , it's impossible $0.5^{10}>0.1$)
$$
(1-\sqrt 2)^{10}<0.1^{1}
$$
then it also makes sense
$$
(1-\sqrt2)^{1,000}<0.1^{100}
$$
We can infer that $(1-\sqrt2)^{3,000}<<0.1^{100}$ so it shall not affect the 100th digit to the right of decimal "directly", like 1-0.000...01

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hints**: $(1+\sqrt{2})^{3000}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000}$ is an integer and $(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000}$ is a small positive number.

Can you prove these two facts and use them to get the answer?

Comment: I don't really understand, why did you add $(1 - \sqrt 2)^{3000}$ , this part is essentially 0, correct ?

Comment: ^Yes it is really small. So $(1+\sqrt{2})^{3000}$ is an integer minus a very small number. What does that tell you about the first several digits to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: it's gonna be all 9s ? thanks.

Comment: if  $( 1 - \sqrt 2 )^{3000}$ is a positive number, why do you say "minus" ?

Comment: We know that $N := (1+\sqrt{2})^{3000}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000}$ is a positive integer. You can prove this by using the binomial theorem, and noticing that all the terms with an odd power of $\sqrt{2}$ cancel out. So, $(1+\sqrt{2})^{3000} = N-(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000}$ is a positive integer minus a very small positive number.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Why is it obvious that $(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000}<<10^{-100}$?

Comment: My post was intended as a hint to OP, not a complete answer. In a complete answer, I would have said something along the lines of $0 < \sqrt{2}-1 < \tfrac{1}{2}$, and so, $0 < (1-\sqrt{2})^{3000} < 2^{-3000} = (2^{10})^{-300} = 1024^{-300} < 1000^{-300} = 10^{-900}$.

Comment: How to prove (1+\sqrt(2))^3000 + (1-\sqrt(2))^3000 is an integer?

Comment: Use the binomial theorem to expand both powers, and then note that the terms where $\sqrt{2}$ is raised to an odd power cancel out.

Answer (score 6):

The way I understand it now is that since 
 $ (1+\sqrt{2})^{2} + (1 - \sqrt{2})^{2} = 6$ 
 $\therefore$ $ (1+\sqrt{2})^{3000} + (1 - \sqrt{2})^{3000} = N$ (N is an integer) 
 since $(1 - \sqrt{2})^{3000}$ would be a very small number so $ (1+\sqrt{2})^{3000} = N - 0.0000...001$ so the 100th digit to the right of the decimal point should be 9

Comment: Mmmm.... I don't like you saying "a small number is 0.00000........0001".  $(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000}$ is quite likely irrational and will not have a final digit of 1.  In fact it is easy (but a waste of time) to prove $(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000} \ne (\frac 1{10})^k$  for any integer $k$.  Also $(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000}$ is a 
"very small number" but how small?  How do you know its 100th digit is 0.  Is it *that* small?  How do you know?  (Hint: is $(1- \sqrt{2})^{3000} < (\frac 1{10})^{100}$?  How do you know?)

Comment: ... also $a + b = 6$ does not mean $a^k + b^k $ is an integer.  $2.5 + 3.5 = 6$ and $2.5^{3} + 3.5^{3} = 58.5$ which is not an integer.  ... Sorry, I'm being a hard-ass but... you are on the right track.  But you can't afford sloppy corner cutting.

Comment: $(1 + \sqrt{2})^k = \sum {3000 \choose k} \sqrt{2}^k$.  $(1 - \sqrt{2})^k = \sum (-1)^k {3000 \choose k} \sqrt{2}^k$.  So $(1 + \sqrt{2})^k+(1 - \sqrt{2})^k = \sum {3000 \choose k}[ \sqrt{2}^k + (-1)^k\sqrt{2}^k]$.  $(-1)^k = -1$ if $k$ is odd and $=1$ if $k$ is even so $(1 + \sqrt{2})^k+(1 - \sqrt{2})^k =$$  \sum_{k \text{ is even}} {3000 \choose k}*2*\sqrt{2}^k$$=  \sum_{k \text{ is even}} {3000 \choose k}*2*2^{k/2}$ which is an integer.  That's the *real* reason.